# Is there a way to do matching pattern using array in perl?

Tags: regex, perl

For example,

```
@seed = ('seed_1', 'seed_2', 'seed_3', 'seed_4);
```

However, in the future there could be more than seed_4. How can I make this as general as possible? Meaning I don't have to manually write the future `seed_`. It can be 'seed_50' or random values.

example:

```
$file ='text.txt';
for my $seed (@seed)
 {
   if (open my $data, "<", $file)
    {
      my $line =<$data>;
      print "ERROR: $line\n";
    }
   close $data;
}
```

the `seed_` are actually folders in directories. So, I need to go through every `seed` to open the text file but I may not know the values in every `seed` folder. The `dir` are directories I need to open. I just need to read out the first line of the text.

so for example:

```
for my $dir (@dir){
    for my $seed (@seed)
     {
       if (open my $data, "<", $file)
        {
          my $line =<$data>;
          print "ERROR: $line\n";
        }
       close $data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Turn that into a regex `seed_1|seed_2|seed_3|seed_4`

Comment: perhaps even `seed_\d+`.

Comment: @Barmar Hi! Do you mean it should be something like this? `@array = (seed 1 |seed_2|seed_3|seed_4)` ? or without the `()`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thank you for the suggestion! I'll try using it.

Comment: @ikegami I have `@array = ('seed_1', 'seed_2', 'seed_3', 'seed_4');`. But in the future, there may be more than this. Is there a way to automatically match the pattern without writing out manually the `seed_` ?

Comment: Thank you for editing and adding an example.  Can you add more to show how is regex with `@seed` elements involved?  (Do you mean to test whether any of `$seed` matches, for each `$line`? Or something else?)

Comment: (I mean even just adding a comment to the code would clarify it (like `# check whether $seed matches $line` or some such)

Comment: Your example doesn't use `$seed`?!? Did you use `$file` where you meant to use `$seed`? If so, you want `glob("\Q$dir\E/seed*")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Escape possible non-"word" ASCII characters in the array elements using [quotemeta](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta), and build a pattern with them using [alternation](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut#Grouping-things-and-hierarchical-matching)

```
my $pattern = join '|', map { quotemeta } @ary;
```

Then use this `$pattern` in a regex pattern

```
if ( $string =~ /$pattern/ ) { say $& }
```

to find the first of elements that matches in the `$string` (if any), or

```
while ( $string =~ /$pattern/g ) { say $& }
```

to iterate over all matches, etc.

Depending on the details it may be necessary to sort the array first.

Comment: Hi, thank you for suggesting this. I tried it and it works. However, if my array increases such as there are seed_1 till seed_10 or random numbers behind `seed_`, do i have to manually type it out in the `@seed`?

Comment: @AlyssaLow No, you never need to type specific elements; that is the point.  The code never names what is in the array -- the whole array is used, whether it has two elements or a thousand.  The `map` applies `quotemeta` (which escapes special characters if there are any) to every element of whatever list you give it, then all those are `join'`-ed with `|`.  The only specific item to provide is the array name (`@seed` in your case instead of `@ary` here)

Comment: @AlyssaLow  The code uses the array (`@seed` in your case) with all its elements.  The array itself has to be formed somehow elsewhere in the code; either you type in those elements, read them from a file, compute them at runtime ... it depends on how your program operates.

Comment: Ohh okay, thank you for the explanation. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Any benefits of making a compiled regex? `my ($pattern) = map { qr/$_/ } ..`

Comment: @Сухой27 Yes, that'd be nice to add, thank you ... I was awaiting some clarifications and now when I see question edits I've got to ponder some more to see what this is about... :)  Will edit then